# Laravel Query Builder to COUNT by Grouping Results that are Common

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

The app that I am building allows teachers to assess their students. They can have any number of students within any number of classes. (For instance, Teacher A may teach only science to one class of 25 students but Teacher B may teach 4 classes of 30 students 7 different subjects.) My end goal is to graph the performance data of any selected class for a teacher. This is what that graph might look like: [image: An example of the data, displayed visually.]

I have a MySQL table with a series of data. The structure for it looks like this:

```
id   user_id  room_id  student_id  subject_id  unit_id  outcome_id  assessed_level
200  28       50       69          23          203      849         4
201  28       50       66          23          203      849         3
202  28       50       76          23          203      849         2
203  28       50       69          23          212      849         4
204  28       50       66          23          212      849         1
205  28       50       76          23          212      849         3

etc.
```

Within a view, I want to grab all of the students for each of the subjects and determine how many achieved 1-4 as an average of their marks. They may have been assessed any number of times in a subject, and I need to output data for all of the subjects that are taught in this chosen classroom, so I determined that I need to run it all through a loop.

I am using the following to get the data:

```
for($x=0; $x<count($students_of_room); $x++) {
    $assessment_data[] = DB::table('student_assessments') 
        ->join('subjects', 'student_assessments.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
        ->select('student_assessments.student_id as student_id', 'subjects.name as subject_name', DB::raw('round(avg(student_assessments.assessed_level)) AS average')) 
        ->where('student_assessments.user_id', Auth::id()) 
        ->where('student_assessments.room_id', $selected_room->id) 
        ->where('student_assessments.student_id', $students_of_room[$x]->id) 
        ->groupBy('student_assessments.subject_id')
        ->get();
}
```

which produces these results:

> [{"student_id":69,"subject_name":"Science","average":"4"}]
>   [{"student_id":66,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":76,"subject_name":"Science","average":"2"}]
>   [{"student_id":67,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":64,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":68,"subject_name":"Science","average":"2"}]
>   [{"student_id":75,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":73,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":74,"subject_name":"Science","average":"2"}]
>   [{"student_id":70,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":65,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":62,"subject_name":"Science","average":"2"}]
>   [{"student_id":63,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":71,"subject_name":"Science","average":"3"}]
>   [{"student_id":72,"subject_name":"Science","average":"1"}]

I would like to be able to group these results together so that all of the students who have an average of 4 are together, the 3s are together, the 2s, and the 1s.

From the example output above, I would have 1 student at a **4**, 9 students at a **3**, 4 students at a **2**, and 1 student at a **1**.

I would like it to look something like this:

> [{"subject_name":"Science","level":"4","num_students":"1"}]
>   [{"subject_name":"Science","level":"3","num_students":"9"}]
>   [{"subject_name":"Science","level":"2","num_students":"4"}]
>   [{"subject_name":"Science","level":"1","num_students":"1"}]

**How could I go about getting this result?**

*Also, if there are other issues where my code could be improved, I am open to that as well. Thanks!*

Comment: I don't completely follow your logic/problem, but my guess that you don't need a loop here.  Let MySQL worry about looping, and you only need to formulate the correct query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as he said, You have to make complex query which will execute faster than the loop you've made

Comment: The reason that I am looping is that I need to get an indeterminate number of records within an indeterminate number of subjects. I'll update my question.

Comment: @SheldonScott add more details so we might help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and Sagar: I have updated the question a bit. I hope it's more clear now. My apologies, too - I am a hobbyist programmer trying to learn the ropes the best I can ;)

Comment: @SheldonScott can you explain `$students_of_room` variable please

Comment: @SagarGautam - The teacher selects a classroom that they want to see the assessment data for. The $students_of_room is a count on the number of students that make up the selected room.

Comment: @SheldonScott okay thats good

Comment: @SheldonScott I've added my answer, please have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think following query will give you the first result, please have a try.

```
DB::table('student_assessments')
->join('subjects', 'student_assessments.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
->where('student_assessments.user_id', Auth::id()) 
->where('student_assessments.room_id', $selected_room->id)
->select('student_assessments.id','subject.name as subject_name','subject.id as subject_id',DB::raw('round(avg(student_assessments.assessed_level)) AS average'))
->groupBy('subject_id','id')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only thing I am noticing different between your query and my original is the addition of some extra selects and grouping by subject_id and id (as opposed to just subject_id). Is that correct? Regardless, this query didn't work the way I was hoping—it outputs every record in the DB, instead of totaling the results up.

Comment: @SheldonScott I've thought it should work, Other might give you some good solution